Enhance NestJS/TypeORM job
I have this CronJob function that creates invoices for my users at the beginning of each month:
    const users = await this.usersRepository.find({
      where: {
        status: UserStatus.ACTIVE,
      },
      relations: ['plans'],
    });

    let date = new Date();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth();
    var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);

    // looping on all users to check ones to create invoice for
    users.forEach(async (user: User) => {
      // Checking if user already have an invoice for this month
      const thisMonthUserInvoice = await this.invoicesRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('invoice')
        .where('invoice.user_id = :user_id', { user_id: user.id })
        .andWhere(
          `invoice.dueDate
        BETWEEN :begin
        AND :end`,
          { begin: firstDay, end: lastDay },
        )
        .getMany();


      if (thisMonthUserInvoice?.length == 0) {
        await this.invoicesRepository.save({
          dueDate: new Date(
            new Date().getFullYear(),
            new Date().getMonth(),
            user.paymentDate.getDate(),
          ),
          plans: user.plans,
          user: user,
          note: 'Monthly Auto Generated Invoice',
        });
      }
    });

Everything is working fine on my production server for now, however users query is fetching almost 20K records, so I am aware of performance issues later on.
Do you suggest a better approach?

if that might help, I can split users into batches by companyId, where each user is related to company and each company has a group of users

